# How do I use custom assembler for clang?

Tags: c, clang, cross-compiling

I've compiled clang to use it as a cross compiler for ARM (by configuring it with `./configure --target=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` ), but when I try to compile any C code, it tries to use `/usr/bin/as`. I already have binutils compiled for ARM, and they are in a separate directory. How do I direct clang (or llvm) to use the assembler that I specify?

Comment: I know I did this recently - let me see if I have configure files around.  For ARM shouldn't it be using the machine code generator instead of trying to run an assembler anyway?  Did you try passing `--integrated-as`?  Can you show an example command line and output from using `-v`?

Comment: My configure line, though it doesn't look like much help:  `../llvm/configure --target=mipsel-sde-elf --prefix=/some/prefix --enable-optimized`.  This did work fine and ran `/some/prefix/mipsel-sde-elf-as`.  That said, I normally use the integrated assembler, so  I haven't tested in a while.

Comment: @CarlNorum I also do have the integrated assembler(`armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-llvm-as`) in the same folder as clang, yet it's still using `/usr/bin/as`. I'm not sure whether `armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-llvm-as` internally calls `/usr/bin/as` though.

Comment: using the `-v` flag on your invocation should show you every tool that gets run with complete command lines.

Comment: @CarlNorum `-v` flag only shows the invocation of `/usr/bin/as`.

Comment: Then `clang` is calling it directly.  Time to source dive I guess! It's quite possible there are bugs in there.  Luckily, the clang/LLVM source is pretty easy to digest.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Right now I want to use /usr/bin/llvm-as instead of /usr/bin/as.

Comment: when you run clang to compile for ARM, even if you use the arm-targeted version, it will try to target the host architecture, so you need to specify the target architecture.

Answer (score 2):

try passing the --host option to configure which will cause all the cc ar etc utilities to prefix with armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-
eg:

```
./configure --host=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --build=i686-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Since you are using configure with hopefully autotools take a look at: 
[automake Cross compiling](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html)

Comment: I think you had misunderstood the question. @JosephH is asking how to cross compile programs using clang, but your answer is relating to "how to cross compile clang itself".

Answer (score 0):

I've always had trouble configuring from the source directory using ./configure and gave up in the end. These days I always configure from a separate directory i.e. ..//configure although I'm told it's recommended to use an absolute path for configure.

Your ARM binutils should be installed in the same prefix you're using for clang and make sure that they're in the path when you configure & build clang - i.e. PATH=/some/prefix/bin:$PATH; /configure --target=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf. If you're keeping them in separate directories for packaging purposes then make install DESTDIR= should help.

I don't generally build clang but the buildscripts I use for devkitARM might be helpful - http://sourceforge.net/p/devkitpro/buildscripts/ci/c372699fc7b4de90eb044314ce5bed04db640291/tree/

Comment: Sorry, but I've never configured clang in the same directory as the source directory before. The command that I have included in my question omitted the `--prefix` flag for brevity. As you can see from  CarlNorum's comments, I did notice his inclusion of the `--prefix` flag, and it still didn't work for me. The strange thing is that the compilation process indeed seems to create the integrated assembler binary in the `bin` (with the correct target triple) folder, yet it never uses it. I'll definitely take a look at the build script you've included in your answer.